# SharedPreferences overwrite other value

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a problem with the `SharedPreferences` If I want to save two different values. I tried with this code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSherlockActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

editor.putInt(getString(R.string.SavedStartSilentHour), hour);
editor.commit();

editor.putInt(getString(R.string.SavedStartSilentMinute), min);
editor.commit();

// One editor.commit() is enough
```

If I run this code the first value is overwritten with the seccond value. If I delte the second part the value is saved correctly. Why is that?

Comment: Post the xml file where your `<string name="SavedStartSilentHour">` is defined.

Comment: That's it thank you! Sometimes you can't see the forest because of so many trees... Thank you.

Comment: @user2246674 I guess it would be good to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems perfect!

You could simplify the thing by committing all the stuff after all the "puts" operations. Although I don't think that this could be your problem...

Just make sure `SavedStartSilentHour` and `SavedStartSilentMinutes` xml's defined values are correctly defined, i.e., if they are the same of course they will be overwritten. (This is the only one thing that makes any sense to me considering your code).

Let mew know of your progress ;)

Comment: That's it thank you! Sometimes you can't see the forest because of so many trees... I had `<string name="SavedStartSilentHour">0</string><string name="SavedStartSilentMinute">0</string>` I changed the values inside and now it works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove first call to

```
editor.commit();
```

and you will be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure *why* this would make the "first value [..] overwritten with the second value".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely caused by re-using a key such that the second assignment simply overwrites the same-keyed value.

One way to test this hypothesis is to try using simple keys which eliminate such possibility, e.g.:

```
editor.putInt("hour", hour);
editor.putInt("min", min);
```

Alternatively, a debugger can be attached and the results of `getString(keyId)` can be compared.

If this does indeed "fix" the issue, then ensure that the `SavedStartSilentHour` and `SavedStartSilentMinute` resources actually evaluate to *different* strings - inspect the resource file itself.